# typeahead not working with what seems to be identical JSON structure, but different data

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I have no idea why, but i have typeahead.js and using the example it works perfectly.  But if i change the data, which looks the same, it does not work.  I cannot understand why:

```
var jdata_1 = [{
"urRouteName": "Test Route Name"
}, {
"urRouteName": "Beesmore Road"
}];
var jdata = [{
"val": "Alabama"
}, {
"val": "Alaska"
}, {
"val": "Arizona"
}, {
"val": "Arkansas"
}];


var routeName = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
},
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: jdata_1
});

routeName.initialize();

$('#routeName').typeahead({
highlight: true
}, {
displayKey: 'urRouteName',
//displayKey: 'val',
source: routeName.ttAdapter()
});
```

Using 'jdata' with displaykey 'val' works a treat.

But using 'data_1' with displaykey 'urRouteName' fails, but no error.

No idea why ?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrAddy/pegp21r7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update the `datumTokenizer`

```
datumTokenizer: function (d) {
   return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.urRouteName);
}
```

Here is a friendly [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pegp21r7/1/)

Comment: I have spent most of the day trying to work out why it would not work.  I would kiss you if you was close :)   Thank you!!!

Comment: Lol. You got me laughing :D You're most welcome :) I'm glad it helped